# Upgrading Jekyll 4 broke - sitemap_generator.rb:129:in `block in fill_pages': undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: macos, jekyll

Hi upgraded my installation to 4.0 and it broke my setup entirely
I am running on MacOS, ruby 3.2.0, Jekyll 4.0.1

```
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.2
Using ffi 1.13.1
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using i18n 1.8.5
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using jekyll-sass-converter 2.1.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.3.3
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Using rexml 3.2.4
Using kramdown 2.3.0
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using rouge 3.25.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Fetching jekyll 4.0.1
Installing jekyll 4.0.1
Using jekyll-feed 0.15.1
Using jekyll-seo-tag 2.7.1
Using minima 2.5.1
```

```
**MacBook-Pro:$ bundle exec jekyll serve**
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
    Configuration file: _config.yml
       Source: /Users/Documents/www.xxxxxx.com
       Destination: /Users/Documents/www.xxxxxxx.com/_site
     Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
          Generating... 
           Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                        ------------------------------------------------
          Jekyll 4.0.1   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                         for any additional information or backtrace. 
                        ------------------------------------------------
    /_plugins/sitemap_generator.rb:129:in `block in fill_pages': undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
    
              if File.exists?(page.path)
                     ^^^^^^^^
    Did you mean?  exist?
        from /_plugins/sitemap_generator.rb:127:in `each'
        from _plugins/sitemap_generator.rb:127:in `fill_pages'
        from _plugins/sitemap_generator.rb:84:in `generate'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:185:in `block in generate'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:183:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:183:in `generate'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `process'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.1/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:476:in `exec'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /Users//.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Nothing changed except upgrade and when I run bundle exec Jekyll serve or build, it is throwing the error above.

Thanks

Comment: _plugins/sitemap_generator.rb:129:in `block in fill_pages': undefined method `exists?' for File:Class (NoMethodError) - if it worked before, there must be a change in your Jekyll, layout or post fles that causes the error. And, check the known issues at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap#known-issues

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know much but if you write the code correctly itll say something about how it didn’t work when in fact it did work.  You gotta try reinstalling the app maybe or even restart your pc and c what happened

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.
Removed non MacOS version of Ruby.
Installed chruby
Installed Jekyll

Worked.